# Quantum mechanics question in derivation of Heisenberg-Euler Lagrangian in Schwartz "QFT" notes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics

In http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1246957.files/IV-9-EffectiveActions.pdf (Page 20) Schwartz derives the Heisenberg-Euler Lagrangian using Schwinger's proper time method.

To do so, he introduces states $|x\rangle$ which are eigenstates of the position operator $\hat x^\mu$ (in the Schroedinger picture) with $\hat x^\mu |x \rangle = x^\mu |x\rangle$ . In the Heisenberg picture we have $\hat x^\mu(s) = e^{i \hat H s} \hat x^\mu e^{-i \hat H s}$, where $$\hat H = - (\hat p^\mu - e A^\mu(\hat x)  )^2 + \frac{e}{2} F_{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\mu\nu} = -\hat \Pi^2 + \frac{e}{2}F_{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\mu\nu}$$ is the Hamiltonian, $\hat \Pi^\mu = p^\mu -e A^\mu(\hat x)$ and $s$ the proper time.
The time-dependent states are given by $|x;s\rangle = e^{-i\hat Hs} |x\rangle$.

How does one derive eq. (153) and (154)?
$$
(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} - e \mathbf{A}) \langle y;0 \ |x; s\rangle = \langle y;0\ |\mathbf{\Pi}(0)|x;s\rangle   \tag{153} $$
$$( i\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{y}} - e \mathbf{A}) \langle y;0 \ |x; s\rangle = \langle y;0\ |\mathbf{\Pi}(s)|x;s\rangle \tag{154}
$$
It probably has to do (which is clear to me, in principle) with the momentum operator being a derivative in position space:
$$
\langle x|p^\mu|\psi\rangle = -i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \langle x\ |\psi\rangle
$$
where $|\psi\rangle$ is some state in Hilbert space, but I don't see how to derive the equations above.